# When reading HTML5 form using PHP, $_POST is not reading inputs. $_REQUEST worked once then stopped

Tags: php, html, forms

HTML:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="tel" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$mail='kenhaki@gmail.com';
$nombre = $_REQUEST['name'];
$telefono = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$mensaje = $_REQUEST['message'];
$headers = 'From: ccontacto@nhtt.com.mx' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: cContacto@nhtt.com.mx' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$thank="gracias.html";

$message = "
nombre15: $nombre
telefono: $telefono
email: $email
mensaje: $mensaje";

if (mail($mail,"Formulario de Contacto Nuevo",$message,$headers))
Header ("Location: $thank");

?>
```

JS:

```
// Contact form
    var form = $('#main-contact-form');
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            beforeSend: function(){
                form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

I'm a beginner, I have been searching through similar questions but haven't found an explanation of why it won't get the fields from the html form.
I have tried using $_REQUEST and $_POST but none work. I have the same form in another part of the same site where it works fine, maybe here the JS is blocking it somehow?

Thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: Verify the actual request, as sent by the browser.

Comment: Are you able to see how the request is being sent from the browser using console tools? If not - a quick way of seeing all the incoming variables is by var dumping all vars used by php - eg: get_defined_vars  or using the code var_dump(get_defined_vars());

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, now the $_REQUEST is not working either, I'm losing it. I have no idea how to do var_dump but I will google about it see how that can help.

Comment: In Chrome you press F12 to open the console, then under the Network tab you click "Preserve Log."  You can now see exactly what the browser is sending to the PHP page.

Comment: You need to read some high quaity tutorials and learn about how PHP operates and how you check error logs and how to check data values, *before* asking SO to help you. **You** need to learn PHP; please read some recommended tutorials

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding the default form action with `event.preventDefault()`. Then all your AJAX call is doing, is requesting the contents of `sendemail.php` - it's not sending any data to it!

Try altering your JS code to this:

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');

form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        method: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks David, I will try that at night and will let you know how it went.

Comment: Hi David, I tried the amend you posted and it made the whole page not to load. I then removed it and the page loads normally.

Comment: It shouldn't prevent the page from loading - it's just javascript.

Comment: I guess, but it did, I tried a couple of times, whenever I enabled your suggestion, and I copied/pasted from here, the page would hang, then I commented it to disable and the page worked again.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for even taking the time to help me man.

Comment: I've updated to show the entire code block. When the page hangs, do you see any errors in the console/web inspector?

Comment: @o5cardiaz you need to look into exploring and learning how the browser feedback console works, how to use it and how to manage Javascript. You probably have a syntax error somewhere